# AWS IOT Button: Connect To Wifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have an AWS IOT button that i'm trying to connect to the open wifi at my office. The problem is, our open "no-auth" wifi has one of those "terms of use" buttons you have to click in a browser before you are connected. Can the AWS IOT button get passed that?

Seems like it only works on wifi that is locked down vie SSA.

Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- discover the device's mac address
- remove the device's power source
- configure your laptop's wifi card to override its built-in MAC address and instead assume the IoT device's MAC address
- sign on to the wireless network and accept terms with your laptop, spoofing the device's hardware address
- return the laptop to normal configuration
- power up the IoT device
- PROFIT! :)  ...at least until the portal's login timeout window expires.

Comment: This would likely work. I guess I was hoping for a more "out of the box" solution. :) Thanks Michael.

Comment: Would likely work indeed, but at least it my case it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately the button doesn't support captive portal networks.
>   Normally we advise the network operator to whitelist the button's MAC
>   address, but I see you've already ruled that out.
>
> One option you have is to use a travel router to bridge the captive
>   portal network to a non-captive portal network. These travel routers
>   are typically designed for hotel use, and so handle captive portal
>   networks well. You'll probably have to first connect to the
>   non-captive network with a phone or laptop to click agree, but then
>   all other devices on the network shouldn't see the login page
>   afterwards.
>
> Note that this may be seen as circumventing the captive portal
>   network's usage or security policies, so please check with the network
>   operator.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244348